# Android Menu item not clickable after 'swiping'

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I walked into (imho) strange behaviour regarding the Menu of Android.

### The *Problem:*

When you place your finger on the menu item (in form of a water-drop) (which is parent of the submenu/group) and **swipe** it down, **select** an option and **release** your finger, everything works out fine.

**BUT** afterwards you're **not able** to press the drop menu item **a second time.**

### What I have:

This is how it looks inside the App:

[image]

1 . Menu registered like this:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        ...
}
```

2 . The Style for the Menu is something like this:
(The group does not seem to be direct responsible)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
<item ... >
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_fuelTypeDiesel" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_fuelTypeE5" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_fuelTypeE10" />
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>
...
</menu>
```

3 . An onOptionsItemSelected-Listener with a Switch-Case-Statement containing something like the following:

```
 case R.id.menu_fuelTypeDiesel:
                someMethod(item);
                break;
```

Where someMethod calls item.setChecked(true); and some unimportant stuff.

What's interesting aswell: When you select another menu Item, which has not been shown on the ActionBar, you can press the Drop afterwards again.

I guess this is a kind of bug within Android?

Comment: Does this happen with non-group menu items also?

Comment: This also occurs by not using a group.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle drag-to-select of sub-menu items on Kitkat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23413116/how-to-handle-drag-to-select-of-sub-menu-items-on-kitkat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in KitKat.

There is an issue on Google Code here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69205